# C++ Input errors when entering a floating point instead of integer

Tags: c++, function, validation, input

I'm trying to write something for class that is basically a tiny online store. The idea is to display some amount of stock, ask the user how many he/she wants, and display the cart when they are finished. I have everything I need and it runs perfectly unless the user says they want a floating point amount of something.
We are supposed to check all inputs for errors and continue to ask the user until a correct input is entered. What I have accounts for any entry (that I know of) consisting of letters and numbers, but when a decimal is entered, it rounds down to the nearest integer, uses that for the current item, then skips to the next input chance (the next item) and immediately gives an error message there.

```
void printError(int stock, int &numberOfCopies){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid amount" << endl << "Enter a number from 0 - " << stock ><< ": ";
        cin >> numberOfCopies;
}

int getQuantity(string title, int stock){
    int numberOfCopies;
    cin >> numberOfCopies;
    while (cin.fail() || numberOfCopies < 0 || numberOfCopies > stock){
        printError(stock, numberOfCopies);
    }
        if (numberOfCopies == 1){
            cout << endl << numberOfCopies << " copy of " << title << " has been >added to your cart" << endl;
        }
        else if (numberOfCopies > 1 && numberOfCopies <= stock){
            cout << endl << numberOfCopies << " copies of " << title << " have >been added to your cart" << endl;
        }
        else if (numberOfCopies == 0){
            cout << "You did not change your cart" << endl;
        }
    return numberOfCopies;
}
int numberOfCopies1 = getQuantity(title1, stock1);
```

This is what I have to check for errors right now (title1 and stock1 are predefined). I'm using `cin.fail()` to check for values that aren't integers, but it doesn't work when entering decimals.
What am I overlooking here?

Comment: You should use `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` instead of `INT_MAX` to clear the whole stream. But if you need to clear the stream before arbitrary input operations, you probably have something wrong. You should clear the stream after every failed input, not before every attempted input "just in case"

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Please describe the actual problem more specifically than "freaks out". Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when a decimal is entered, it rounds down to the nearest integer, uses that for the current item, then skips to the next input chance (the next item) and immediately gives an error message

That's the way streams are meant to work, so they can be used to parse `int`s that are meant to be followed by whatever-other separators or content.  If you want to treat that as an error - checking that there's no trailing garbage - you should use `std::getline`, after which it's usually convenient to construct a `std::istringstream` to get the `int` from, checking there's no garbage thereafter:

```
std::string line;
while (getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (line >> n >> std::ws && iss.eof())
        break;
    ...clear/ignore/prompt again...
}
```

The `getline` / `istringstream` dance matches the amount of input you can expect from `std::cin` when prompting for a single integer - if you directly used `std::cin >> n >> std::ws && std::cin.eof()`, it would only fail if `std::cin` hit EOF - e.g. the user typed Control-D on a UNIX/Linux host,  Control-Z on Windows etc., after which they might not be able to enter any more text (depends on the exact OS).

Note that streaming to a `float` or `double` then checking it's equal to the `floor` of itself would solve the exact problem you reported, but then if someone types other nonsense "27x", "27O", you'll still extract the leading integer part and have the rest trigger an error report the next time....